# C help in using system function with batch

Tags: c, batch-file, system

Hello I have a small problem with my C program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char buff[120];
    char text;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    gets(buff);
    text = sprintf(buff, "echo StrText=\"%s\" > spk.vbs");
    system(text);
    system("echo set ObjVoice=CreateObject(\"SAPI.SpVoice\") >> spk.vbs");
    system("echo ObjVoice.Speak StrText >> spk.vbs");
    system("start spk.vbs");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get input from a user and apply it in the system() function?. I am new to C and I am mostly a batch coder, I am trying to port some applications to C so Can anyone tell me to write this application without using the system function?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: instead of using echo you should use fwrite and WinExec (windows) to start your script

Comment: Btw, aren't you contradicting yourself a little? _How can I get input from a user and apply it in the system() function?_ and then _without using the system function?_ Do you want to use `system` or not?

Comment: yes I am sorry. Exactly like that. How can I get input from a user and write this to a file and then execute it?

Comment: @OsandaMalith But why do you want to store the command in the file and then execute it? Isn't it easier to just execute what the user inputs? If you want to write to file, read the file and then execute its contents please confirm, though I find the arrangement unusual.

Comment: I want to get the input from a user and speak it using the vbs script. For that I want to add the user input to the echo StrText=\"%s\" > spk.vbs part of the file. That's all I want to do. If you know any other method of doing this let me know :)

Comment: @OsandaMalith See my post edit, I think it does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your includes:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Change your `char text;` to `char text[120];` - has to be an array, not a single char

Then replace `gets` with `fgets`:

```
fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin); /* for sizeof(buff) to work buff and fgets must be in the same scope */

buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0'; /* this will trim the newline character for you */
```

Finally you pass `text` to `system` after you've formatted it to your purposes (perhaps something like):

```
sprintf(text, "echo StrText=\"%s\" > spk.vbs", buff);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Note: You should also include `#include <stdlib.h>` for your `system` call. Always compile with warnings (`gcc -Wall -Wextra` if you are on Linux), it will be pointed out for you.

Is this what you need?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char buff[120];
    char text[120];

    printf("Enter your command: ");

    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);

    buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0'; /* get rid of the newline characters */

    sprintf(text, "echo StrText=\"%s\" > spk.vbs", buff);

    system(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the applications crashes :/

Comment: @OsandaMalith I'm still not sure what you need but see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

gets is deprecated. Use fgets instead.

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char inputBuf[120];
    char cmdBuf[200];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(inputBuf , sizeof( inputBuf) - 1 , stdin );
    sprintf(cmdBuf, "echo StrText=\"%s\" > spk.vbs" , inputBuf );
    system(cmdBuf);
    return 0;
}
```